# Re-install an existing custom Windows Service on remote machine

Tags: windows, deployment, service, windows-services, rdp

On the server (RDP), there is a Windows Service that does some action with database of the website periodically. This service is developed by another programmer and now I'm continuing his job and made some changes to the logic of service.

The current service is up and running. Logged on as a network service, start type = automatic,  status = started.

I need to update/deploy the service so my changes will take effect and the service will start running with the new logic.

My question is, what is the main action that I need to take? I've the path of the current service's executable files (source location of the service) as well as the new executables and DLLs on my hand.
Do I need to uninstall and then install the new service? Or may be I've to stop the service, then replace the .exe file in service path and then just start the service again?

I'm afraid to break anything as it is my first time to work with WinServices. 
I've stuck on this. 
Google didn't help much.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps

1. In order to deploy new executable you need to uninstall the current running service.
2. take the backup of current excutable into new place
3. Place the new
       excutable and install the service. and start it from the services
       window.

If you find any problems  then uninstall the new one.install the current running service.